# How can I give access to my Azure Function for an external systems webhook?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, webhooks, azure-authentication

I have an Azure Function with Identity Provider Microsoft as Authentication.
The Azure Function triggers when a post request is sent with an event from the webhook.

I am not 100% sure yet, how much I can configure the webhook other than that I can add an event, a body, and the url that the webhook should send the post request to.
How can I give this webhook access to the Azure Function with oauth2 token?
Is this easily achievable or is there something else I should do?
Is it good enough to use Azure App Keys instead? And just add that to the webhook body.

Looking for tips on how to attack this task, as I am not very familiar with webhooks and authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhooks are tricky to secure with Oauth because you typically need multiple requests to first fetch the token and then issue the actual request.

If the Azure Function key is sufficient security for your purposes (your infrastructure person if you have one should be able to weigh in on that) then use it. If you need to go oauth, I don't have a good solution for that.

Comment: Thank you. Seeing as the webhook is private and secured with an api key, and communicating with only the azure function which fetches all sensitive data from a key vault, would it be wrong to assume it is safe to go with Azure Functions App key?

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: It's on you to determine if it's "safe". For many use cases it's 'good enough'.  Are there regulatory or compliance factors at play? Think about who might be able to see that key. Could they use it for nefarious purposes? Does your org have an arch review board or something similar? Ideally developers don't make these decisions alone.

Comment: Those who have access to where they can see the key will not be able to do anything more with the key that they wouldn't already without it. So in that case, I am not worried that the security is not optimal. It should be 'good enough' using App keys, I just wanted to follow best practice. I appreciate your insight, thank you :)